# Spring batch custom reader to map all the values to array field

Tags: java, spring-batch

Hi folks i am new in spring batch and stuck in below problem, requesting to give some suggestion

Problem statement = spring batch reader after reading data it should map to array field

```
input file(tab seprated)
val1    val2    val3
va21    va22    va23
va31    va32    va33

Pojo
class SamplePojo{
  private Object[] value;
}
```

reader should map the field as mention below

```
output pojo
value[0] = val1
value[1] = va12
value[2] = va13

value[0] = va21
value[1] = va22
value[2] = va23

value[0] = va31
value[1] = va32
value[2] = va33
```

how can i configure my reader to achive above output

Comment: Read `Spring-Batch` documentation, and write an `ItemReader<T>`

Answer (score 1):

[FieldSetMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/FieldSetMapper.html) is the strategy interface that allows you to customize how tokenized lines are mapped to domain objects. In your case, you can use a `FlatFileItemReader` with a `DelimitedLineTokenizer` and a custom `FieldSetMapper`. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SO72571852 {

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Pojo> itemReader() throws Exception {
        DefaultLineMapper<Pojo> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(" "));
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new FieldSetMapper<Pojo>() {
            @Override
            public Pojo mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
                Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
                Object[] values = new Object[3];
                values[0] = fieldSet.readString(0);
                values[1] = fieldSet.readString(1);
                values[2] = fieldSet.readString(2);
                pojo.values = values;
                return pojo;
            }
        });

        FlatFileItemReader<Pojo> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("input.tsv"));
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        flatFileItemReader.afterPropertiesSet();
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Pojo> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {items.forEach(System.out::println);};
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) throws Exception {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .<Pojo, Pojo>chunk(5)
                        .reader(itemReader())
                        .writer(itemWriter())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
                .build();
    }

    static class Pojo {
        private Object[] values;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pojo{values=" + Arrays.toString(values) + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SO72571852.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }


}
```